# xypic bending arrows whith non-default shafts

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I have troubles trying to bend double arrows in XYpic. Here is my code at the moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
\ar@2 `r[r] [dr] &
\\
& &
}
\]
\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be that the `ar@2` part is not applied where the arrow is bent. Is there an easy way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer you a version with [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd). This package is much more modern and you should consider changing to this.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
    \arrow[Rightarrow, to path=-| (\tikztotarget), rounded corners=10]{dr} & \\
    & \null
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As a compromise towards `xy` I can just offer this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
    \ar@/^1pc/@{=>}[dr] &
    \\
    & &
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Not the same curve, but it shows in the same direction :-) But it looks totally ugly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I have to stick with `xy`for the time being because I am using some custom shafts (namely: 3 and 4-cells) and I don't know how to make them in `tikz-cd`.
Also I knew about the `@/^/` trick but it is quite limited for more complicated examples.

Comment: @skysurf3000 Well, if you want, you can give me that custom stuff and I translate it into Ti*k*Z. If it is not too much.

Comment: In standard `xy` you can make triple arrows thanks to `\ar@3` (which looks like `\Rrightarrow`). The custom thing I use extends that to `\ar@4` to make quadruple arrows. I put the code there if you want to take a look: (http://pastebin.com/xE06FVWA).